# When is the product topology equal to products of open sets in component spaces?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of topological spaces.  When is the topology of $\prod_i X_i$ equal to $\mathcal{T} = \left\{ \prod_i U_i : U_i \in \mathcal{T}(X_i)\right\}$ where $\mathcal{T}(X_i)$ is the topology on $X_i$, and $U_i$'s in those products are $\neq X_i$ for only finitely many $i$.

**My attempt:**

The open sets in the product topology are arbitrary unions of sets in the $\mathcal{T}$ described above, by [Wikipedia's definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology#Definition).  So each open set is of the form
$$\bigcup_{j \in J} \prod_{i \in I} U_i^j.$$

But here I'm stuck because $(A\times B) \cup (C\times D) \neq (A\cup C) \times (B \cup D) $ in general.

Comment: If only one topology is nontrivial then the result holds. By trivial I mean $\tau=\{X,\varnothing\}$. I would guess these are the only cases.

Comment: And if two topologies are non-trivial, then it cannot hold.

Comment: What am I thinking of then?  I've seen something to the effect of the open sets are products of open sets.  Or can this be done with the closed sets only?

Comment: Even with closed sets, not every closed set in the product is the product of closed sets. However, the products of open sets form a basis of a topology (the Box-topology) on the product (if the number of nontrivial factors is finite, the Box-topology is the product topology).

Comment: I think there's confusion here between a *basis* for a topology and the topology itself.

Comment: Often times it is enough to prove something on a basis for your topological space, so in many situations you can assume your open set is of this form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set

$$\mathcal{T} = \left\{ \prod_i U_i : U_i \in \mathcal{T}(X_i)\right\}$$

is a topology (assuming $I \neq \varnothing$) if and only if at least one factor $X_i$ is empty, or at most one factor does not carry the indiscrete topology.

If one factor is empty, we have $X = \varnothing$ and $\mathcal{T} = \{\varnothing\}$, so it's a topology.

If at most one factor does carry a topology other than the indiscrete topology,say $X_0$, then up to reordering indices

$$\mathcal{T} = \left\{ U_0 \times \prod_{i\neq 0} X_i : U_0 \in\mathcal{T}(X_0)\right\}$$

which is isomorphic to $\mathcal{T}(X_0)$, hence a topology.

If two spaces have at least two distinct non-empty open sets, say $X_0$ and $X_1$ with distinct non-empty open sets $U_0 \not\subset V_0$ and $U_1 \not \supset V_1$, then

$$\left(U_0\times U_1 \times \prod_{i \neq 0,1}X_i\right) \cup \left(V_0 \times V_1 \times \prod_{i \neq 0,1}X_i\right)$$

is a set that is not of the form $\prod\limits_i U_i$.